# How to proxy API requests from React app to separate Express server in production

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, request, production

I’ve deployed one React app and one Express server separately to Heroku. In development, requests from React are automatically proxied through the proxy option in package.json. I am aware, however, that this does not work in production.

I would therefore like to ask what the best workaround for this is? Obviously prefixing all the routes with the API url would not be very clean. I also tried this with one route, but the React app prefixed the API url with the client url.

Answer (score 0):

Try hash routing in React. It'll solve route redirection in the cleanest way possible

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. All api requests are done in a separate module, so would this still be applicable there? I was wondering if there was something similar to the proxy option for development that would automatically redirect external requests to the API.